# WHMCS Bridge Affiliates link not working properly?

Tags: wordpress, whmcs, affiliate

direct whmcs links work like a charm
if you use http://billing.serverturbo.com for example
affiliate clicks get counted and also signups are tracked
but if you use the bridge links
like http://serverturbo.com/dedicated-servers for example
it doesn't work
clicks also get counted
but no signups
the user can signup but he won't be counted as affiliate
thats the issue
so the full link looks similar to this: serverturbo.com/dedicated-servers?ccce=aff&aff=010&pid=1